# How to generate an UIImage from AVCapturePhoto with correct orientation?

Tags: avfoundation, ios11, avcapturesession, swift4

I am calling `AVFoundation`'s delegate method to handle a photo capture, but I am having difficulty converting the `AVCapturePhoto` it generates into an `UIImage` with the correct orientation. Although the routine below is successful, I always get a right-oriented `UIImage` (`UIImage.imageOrientation` = 3). I have no way of providing an orientation when using the `UIImage(data: image)` and attempting to first use `photo.cgImageRepresentation()?.takeRetainedValue()` also doesn't help. Please assist.

Image orientation is critical here as the resulting image is being fed to a Vision Framework workflow.

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    // capture image finished
    print("Image captured.")
    if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
        if let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData){
            // do stuff to UIImage
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Reading Apple's [Photo Capture Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/PhotoCaptureGuide/index.html) (out of date for iOS11), I did manage to find one thing I was doing wrong:

1. On every capture call (`self.capturePhotoOutput.capturePhoto`) one must setup a connection with the `PhotoOutput` object and update its orientation to match the device's orientation at the moment the picture is taken. For doing that, I created an extension of `UIDeviceOrientation` and used it on the `snapPhoto()` function I created to call the capture routine and wait for the `didFinishProcessingPhoto` delegate method to be executed. I've added a snapshot of the code because the code sample delimiters here don't seem to be displaying them correctly.
   [image]
   [image]

**Update 2**
Link to full project on GitHub: https://github.com/agu3rra/Out-Loud

Comment: Interesting, and possibly a [bug to file](http://bugreport.apple.com). Does it also seem to ignore orientation if you write that data to a file and use a file-based `UIImage` initializer?

Comment: After I've added the connection call on the snapPhoto() routine (UPDATE 1), it is no longer ignoring orientation, but it is giving me back incorrect orientation values on the UIImage I create.

Comment: About your orientation extension. Apple has released AVCam updated. There is a similar extension. `extension UIDeviceOrientation {
    var videoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation? {
        switch self {
            case .portrait:           return .portrait
            case .portraitUpsideDown: return .portraitUpsideDown
            case .landscapeLeft:      return .landscapeRight
            case .landscapeRight:     return .landscapeLeft
            default: return nil
        }
    }
}`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 34):

**Final update:**
I ran some experiments with the app and came to the following conclusions:

1. `kCGImagePropertyOrientation` doesn’t seem to influence the orientation of the captured image inside your application and it only varies with the device orientation if you update your `photoOutput` connection each time you are about to call the `capturePhoto` method. So:

   ```
   func snapPhoto() {
       // prepare and initiate image capture routine

       // if I leave the next 4 lines commented, the intented orientation of the image on display will be 6 (right top) - kCGImagePropertyOrientation
       let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation // retrieve current orientation from the device
       guard let photoOutputConnection = capturePhotoOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video) else {fatalError("Unable to establish input>output connection")}// setup a connection that manages input > output
       guard let videoOrientation = deviceOrientation.getAVCaptureVideoOrientationFromDevice() else {return}
       photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = videoOrientation // update photo's output connection to match device's orientation

       let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
       photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
       photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
       photoSettings.flashMode = .auto
       self.capturePhotoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self) // trigger image capture. It appears to work only if the capture session is running.
   }
   ```
2. Viewing the generated images on the debugger has shown me how they get generated, so I could infer the required rotation (`UIImageOrientation`) to get it displayed upright. In other words: updating `UIImageOrientation` tells how the image should be rotated in order for you to see it in the correct orientation. So I came to the following table:
   [image: Which UIImageOrientation to apply according to how the device was at the time of capture]
3. I had to update my `UIDeviceOrientation` extension to a rather unintuitive form:

   ```
   extension UIDeviceOrientation {
       func getUIImageOrientationFromDevice() -> UIImageOrientation {
           // return CGImagePropertyOrientation based on Device Orientation
           // This extented function has been determined based on experimentation with how an UIImage gets displayed.
           switch self {
           case UIDeviceOrientation.portrait, .faceUp: return UIImageOrientation.right
           case UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown, .faceDown: return UIImageOrientation.left
           case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft: return UIImageOrientation.up // this is the base orientation
           case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight: return UIImageOrientation.down
           case UIDeviceOrientation.unknown: return UIImageOrientation.up
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. This is how my final delegate method looks now. It displays the image in the expected orientation.

   ```
   func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                                    didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto,
                                    error: Error?)
   {
       // capture image finished
       print("Image captured.")

       let photoMetadata = photo.metadata
       // Returns corresponting NSCFNumber. It seems to specify the origin of the image
       //                print("Metadata orientation: ",photoMetadata["Orientation"])

       // Returns corresponting NSCFNumber. It seems to specify the origin of the image
       print("Metadata orientation with key: ",photoMetadata[String(kCGImagePropertyOrientation)] as Any)

       guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
           print("Error while generating image from photo capture data.");
           self.lastPhoto = nil; self.controller.goToProcessing();
           return

       }

       guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
           print("Unable to generate UIImage from image data.");
           self.lastPhoto = nil; self.controller.goToProcessing();
           return

       }

       // generate a corresponding CGImage
       guard let cgImage = uiImage.cgImage else {
           print("Error generating CGImage");self.lastPhoto=nil;return

       }

       guard let deviceOrientationOnCapture = self.deviceOrientationOnCapture else {
           print("Error retrieving orientation on capture");self.lastPhoto=nil;
           return

       }

       self.lastPhoto = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: deviceOrientationOnCapture.getUIImageOrientationFromDevice())

       print(self.lastPhoto)
       print("UIImage generated. Orientation:(self.lastPhoto.imageOrientation.rawValue)")
       self.controller.goToProcessing()
   }


   func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, 
                      willBeginCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) 
                      {
       print("Just about to take a photo.")
       // get device orientation on capture
       self.deviceOrientationOnCapture = UIDevice.current.orientation
       print("Device orientation: \(self.deviceOrientationOnCapture.rawValue)")
   }
   ```

Comment: what is `getAVCaptureVideoOrientationFromDevice`?

Comment: Its not a great idea to rely on the `deviceOrientationOnCapture` property that you set, since the delegate can come back before or after that value has already changed (like taking multiple pictures in a row). 

Try my answer that relies on the metadata that comes back from the actual delegate call instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/54225440/753964

Comment: @AntonBelousov he omitted it from his answer but it can be found within his repo here: https://github.com/agu3rra/Out-Loud

Comment: If iPhone auto rotate is tuned off, we cannot rely on the `UIDevice.current.orientation` because it always returns `.portrait` even when the user takes the picture in landscape more.

Answer (score 6):

I've had success doing this:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

        let cgImage = photo.cgImageRepresentation()!.takeRetainedValue()
        let orientation = photo.metadata[kCGImagePropertyOrientation as String] as! NSNumber
        let uiOrientation = UIImage.Orientation(rawValue: orientation.intValue)!
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: uiOrientation)

}
```

It's based on what Apple mention in their docs:

> Each time you access this method, AVCapturePhoto generates a new CGImageRef. When backed by a compressed container (such as HEIC),
>   the CGImageRepresentation is decoded lazily as needed. When backed by
>   an uncompressed format such as BGRA, it is copied into a separate
>   backing buffer whose lifetime is not tied to that of the
>   AVCapturePhoto. For a 12 megapixel image, a BGRA CGImage represents
>   ~48 megabytes per call. If you only intend to use the CGImage for
>   on-screen rendering, use the previewCGImageRepresentation instead.
>   Note that the physical rotation of the CGImageRef matches that of the
>   main image. Exif orientation has not been applied. If you wish to
>   apply rotation when working with UIImage, you can do so by querying
>   the photo's metadata[kCGImagePropertyOrientation] value, and passing
>   it as the orientation parameter to +[UIImage
>   imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:]. RAW images always return a
>   CGImageRepresentation of nil. If you wish to make a CGImageRef from a
>   RAW image, use CIRAWFilter in the CoreImage framework.

Comment: Actually `photo.metadata[kCGImagePropertyOrientation]` is `CGImagePropertyOrientation` not `UIImage.Orientation`
(c) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimagepropertyorientation

Comment: I think it should be `(rawValue: orientation.intValue - 1)`

Answer (score 6):

To create our image with the right orientation we need to enter the correct `UIImage.Orientation` when we initialize the image.

Its best to use the `CGImagePropertyOrientation` that comes back from the photoOutput delegate to get the exact orientation the camera session was in when the picture was taken. Only problem here is that while the enum values between `UIImage.Orientation` and `CGImagePropertyOrientation` are the same, the raw values are not. Apple suggests a simple mapping to fix this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimagepropertyorientation

Here is my implementation:

**AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate**

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let _ = error {
            // Handle Error
        } else if let cgImageRepresentation = photo.cgImageRepresentation(),
            let orientationInt = photo.metadata[String(kCGImagePropertyOrientation)] as? UInt32,
            let imageOrientation = UIImage.Orientation.orientation(fromCGOrientationRaw: orientationInt) {

            // Create image with proper orientation
            let cgImage = cgImageRepresentation.takeUnretainedValue()
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage,
                                scale: 1,
                                orientation: imageOrientation)
        }
    }
```

**Extension for Mapping**

```
extension UIImage.Orientation {

    init(_ cgOrientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation) {
        // we need to map with enum values becuase raw values do not match
        switch cgOrientation {
        case .up: self = .up
        case .upMirrored: self = .upMirrored
        case .down: self = .down
        case .downMirrored: self = .downMirrored
        case .left: self = .left
        case .leftMirrored: self = .leftMirrored
        case .right: self = .right
        case .rightMirrored: self = .rightMirrored
        }
    }


    /// Returns a UIImage.Orientation based on the matching cgOrientation raw value
    static func orientation(fromCGOrientationRaw cgOrientationRaw: UInt32) -> UIImage.Orientation? {
        var orientation: UIImage.Orientation?
        if let cgOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: cgOrientationRaw) {
            orientation = UIImage.Orientation(cgOrientation)
        } else {
            orientation = nil // only hit if improper cgOrientation is passed
        }
        return orientation
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that this doesn't work when rotation lock is on. But none of the other techniques work either, you have to enable the gyroscope and keep track of the device itself. What a hack. I recently burned a DTS incident to find out if there was some other way, Apple laughed at me.

Comment: doesn't work: `orientationInt` always returns the same value

Answer (score 2):

Updated extension provided by Andre which works with Swift 4.2:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIDeviceOrientation {
    var imageOrientation: UIImage.Orientation {
        switch self {
        case .portrait, .faceUp:                return .right
        case .portraitUpsideDown, .faceDown:    return .left
        case .landscapeLeft:                    return .up
        case .landscapeRight:                   return .down
        case .unknown:                          return .up
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `AVCapturePhoto` I’m pretty sure you will find a `metadata` object of the also called `CGImageProperties`.
 
Inside it you will find the EXIF dictionary for orientation the next step is  just to take the orientation and create an image according to that.
I do not have experiences in using `AVCapturePhotoOutput` but I have some using the old way.
Pay attention that the EXIF dictionary is mapped differently in UIImageOrientation.
Here is an [article](http://cloudintouch.it/2014/04/03/exif-pain-orientation-ios/) I wrote a lot of time ago, but the main principle are still valid.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006759/how-to-write-exif-metadata-to-an-image-not-the-camera-roll-just-a-uiimage-or-j) will point you to some implementations, it's pretty old too, I'm pretty sure that in the latest version they released easier API, but it will still guide you into take the issue.